# How to find elements inside a commerce order form with dpm()?

Tags: commerce, entities, debugging

I want to identify a specific field inside a commerce order form. The machine name of the field inside the order form is: `commerce_customer_profile`.

Using Devel Themer I've got:

```
$form['element']['#field_name'] = 'commerce_customer_profile';
```

But I don't know if that's correct, or how programatically get that information?

I know that I could add `dpm($node, 'Debugging node ' . $node->title);` to my node.module file, but **how may I do the same with commerce module without actually hacking it?**

Comment: The commerce order form isn't special, it's just a form. You can use `hook_form_alter()` to hook into it, and `dpm()` to view the contents of the form as you would any other. No hacking required, the duplicate has a code example

Comment: Thanks! I've searched it before posting, but I guess I did it with the wrong keywords, because I didn't find the answer then. Thanks!